# Open source .NET or Mono based library to read cbz/cbr files

Tags: open-source, library, c#, cross-platform, documentation-viewer

Can anyone suggest an open source library which can be used in a cross-platform project (targeting Xamarin Android, iOS, Windows Phone, Windows (desktop GTK project)) to **read .cbz or .cbr files**?

I have found **[SharpZipLib](http://www.sharpziplib.com/)** but not sure whether we can use it in a cross-platform project.

Note: I am trying to read a comic book which is created in cbr or cbz format.

Comment: These file formats are just RAR or ZIP archives, so you are asking the wrong question. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comic_book_archive There should be plenty of libraries for unpacking RAR/ZIP.

Comment: I remember opening such files in Okular, you could check how they do it.

Comment: @Nemo Thank you But i couldn't find any libraries in their site  to re use them in an application.I guess they provide only the Reader application.